# How to test accessbility using Jaws, NVDA, Voice over?

Tags: wcag, wcag2.0

Looking for tips on how to test web applications and websites using accessibility screenreaders like(NVDA,JAWS,VoiceOver) or any specific global tool or any automation tool.

How to test our application if WCAG not covered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I test an application for accessibility I find its important to consider a few things. First might be to know what level of compliance are you targeting and familiarize yourself with those guidelines. No need to go overboard here, but some familiarity is a good thing.

Usually I'm required to adhere to WCAG 2.0 AA and so those are the guidelines I know best. The next thing to consider is what tool set are you planning to use. I generally make use of NVDA and JAWS screen readers and WAVE, aXe, SiteImprove browser extensions to test in the various browsers our application supports.

[Here is a link to JAWS docs](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWSdocumentation) which can help you get started, but know that JAWS requires a license that is not very cheap.

[Here is a link to NVDA docs](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html), this screen reader is free to use.

The browser extension can be found readily enough and are pretty straight forward in their uses. The three I mentioned are ran on a page by page basis and will report findings based on the level of compliance you indicate you're targeting in the extension settings. Note: they will occasionally return different errors, or identify different false-positives. This is one of the main reasons I use multiple, so as to get feedback from multiple sources and make decisions based on all available info.

In addition to running the extensions on a page by page basis there are tools that allow you to provide a list of pages to hit and the accessibility tool will navigate to each of the pages and test the page. One such automated tool is Lighthouse. This requires a lot more effort up front, but could be worth it if the application to test is very large or you'd like to have a type of regression testing in place.

Hope this helps!

Oh, another tool that I've found helpful for color contrast [can be found here](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/).